# Exacttarget JB4A-SDK-Android Gradle Errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, android, bug, salesforce-sdk-android

i'm using this SDK in my app:
http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/
(Version: 4.4.1)

After I included the SDK in my project I got alot of errors in the gradle console:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushConfig$1) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"(com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ad) that doesn\u0027t come with an","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"and without specifying any \"-target\" type options. The consequence of ignoring","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"indicate that it is *not* an inner class.","sources":[{}]}
[...] 384 errors in total
```

I think this is caused by ProGuard which is used to obfuscate the SDK.
Could these errors be removed in an upcoming version?

*Environment:*

Gradle: 2.13

JVM: 1.8.0_74 (Oracle Corporation 25.74-b02)

OS: Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of these errors are caused by Proguard and calls to things like `Thread thread = new Thread();`  Those end up as anonymous inner-classes and generate those messages.  Google Play Services is famous for those as well and Google recommends adding an "ignore" statement to your Proguard configuration file.

Comment: this didn't work for me, my proguard rules are: -keep class com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.** { *; }
-keepattributes InnerClasses
-dontwarn com.exacttarget.**

Comment: I will open an item and put it into the product backlog for prioritization.

Comment: @BillMote This is not a client-side Proguard issue - when we do a Non-Proguard build we see 288 errors from including salesforce SDK, if we include with transitive=true we see 416 errors.  Like the OP we are building with JDK 1.8  There is definitely something wrong in the way the Salesforce SDK is being built.

Comment: I get the same error count (416) when building your LearningAppAndroid  (Debug mode - no Proguard) with JDK 1.8 - so this should be very easy to reproduce.